# Scroll snapping not functioning in react app

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a function in a react app that currently has 3 sections sections under a parent section:

```
type he return (
    <section className="ResourcesPage">
      <section className="resource">
        <p className="resourcesTitle">Here are some resources</p>
        {resourceList.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="resourceListItem">
              <div className="iconContainer">
                <img className="resourceIcon" src={item[3]}></img>
              </div>
              <div className="itemName">{item[0]}</div>
              <div className="actualLink">
                <a className="resourceListLink" href={item[1]} target="_blank">
                  {item[2]}
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <p className="alternateOption">
          &#x2193; Alternatively, you can use the built-in emailing section
          below &#x2193;
        </p>
      </section>

      <section className="resource">
        <Contact />
      </section>

      <div className="bottomEdge layer"></div>
    </section>
  );re
```

I am trying to scroll snap the sections with className resource and I have tried doing so in the .css file with the following code:

```
.ResourcesPage {
  transition: color 0.6s;
  color: var(--text-primary);
  margin-bottom: 6vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.ResourcesPage .resource {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

There are other stylings in the .css file but in regards to the section that I want to scroll snap this is the relevant snippet. The issue is that its not snapping to the new sections.

I have tried changing the option to mandatory instead of proximity and also other overflow-y options as well, but none seem to work.
My understanding is that I need to apply

scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
overflow-y: scroll;

to the parent element and

scroll-snap-align: start;

to the children element and it should work. I think that's is what I have here. Currently, the height of the first section isn't taking up the height of the viewport, but in previous tests I have increased the height to 100vh for the children sections to the point where some text were clipped off the screen and it still didn't work. Additionally, is there an option to make it so that the inner scroll bar is not visible? I want the content to be clipped and be scrollable, but I already have a scroll bar in the outermost parent that uses this exported functional component, so the inner scroll bar is a bit of an eyesore.

[image: additional scrollbar]

Ideally I want to be able to accomplish all of this in CSS.